# why does ssh prompt with the ECDSA key instead of RSA

Tags: ssh, rsa, ecdsa

When I use an Ubuntu from linode

`ssh-keygen -l` defaults to looking for an RSA file to "list".

Yet `ssh` issued from a client asks for verification of the remote linode's ECDSA key.

This means that on the linode the following

`ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` would have to be issued in order to know the key which is inconvenient and hard to remember.

Should it not be that both tools default to RSA or that both tools default to ECDSA. Why are the defaults "out of synch"?

Edit: To clarify, `ssh-keygen -l` seems to default to RSA and it knows the default path. If `ssh` would prompt with an RSA key then `ssh-keygen` can be used with the shorter command. Unfortunately, `ssh` prompts with the ECDSA key.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem really is. Maybe you assume that the key type used to authenticate the server to the client (i.e. key of the server) must match the one used to authenticate the client to the server (i.e. key of the client). This is not the case, i.e. server and client keys are fully independent from each other which also includes what key types are used.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I posted an edit.

Comment: Still not clear what your problem is. `ssh-keygen -l` defaults to keys in the home directory. Thus, for showing the host keys located under `/etc/ssh` instead you would need to add a filename anyway, no matter if RSA or ECDSA.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I want both tools to default to RSA or both to default to ECDSA and I am trying to understand why this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

> ssh-keygen -l seems to default to RSA and it knows the default path.

`ssh-keygen -l` defaults to use a RSA key within the users home directory, i.e. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Keys in the home directory are used to authenticate the client to the server. What you want to verify instead is the host key which is used to authenticate the server against the client. To get this fingerprint you need to specify the key with the `-f` argument no matter if RSA or ECDSA is used since it is not located in the users home directory but in a system directory, typically `/etc/ssh`.

> If ssh would prompt with an RSA key then ssh-keygen can be used with the shorter command. Unfortunately, ssh prompts with the ECDSA key.

SSH prompts with whatever key the server is presenting to the client, i.e. it fully depends on the server setup and not on some SSH builtin defaults.

Comment: "It fully depends on the server setup" okay, I had no opinion about the cause, I only care about the effect. So perhaps openssh-server (or whatever is used by Ubuntu on Linode) by default sends ECDSA to ssh but the implementation of `ssh-keygen -l` defaults to RSA because nobody cares?

Comment: Or is it that the implementation of `ssh-keygen -l` should not be changed because `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is a good default? I never want to look at my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` so for me it is not a good default but perhaps other people have a need.

Comment: @H2ONaCl: *"...I had no opinion about the cause, I only care about the effect. "* - you are claiming that *"both tools"* have different settings. The only tools you mention are `ssh-keygen` and `ssh`.

Comment: Yes, one is defaulting to ECDSA (`openssh-server to ssh`) and the other to RSA (`ssh-keygen -l`)

Comment: *"I never want to look at my ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub so for me it is not a good default but perhaps other people have a need"* - this is a completely different question. Your  original question was only about ECDSA vs. RSA as default. This here is about showing user key (i.e. client key) or host key (server key) as default and then RSA vs. ECDSA on top of it.

Comment: The man page says this: Show fingerprint of specified public key file. Private RSA1 keys are also supported. For RSA and DSA keys ssh-keygen tries to find the matching public key file and prints its fingerprint. If combined with -v, an ASCII art representation of the key is supplied with the fingerprint.

Comment: If it should say something about the local host and something about the remote host then it might be helpful. Otherwise your info about user key/client key and host key/server key is news. You could be right but it's not in the description of the "list" option.

Comment: @H2ONaCl: I have the feeling we are either talking about different things or that you miss some of the basics of SSH, i.e. what the fingerprint presented to you when connecting to a new server actually means (server authentication) and what you need to verify it (fingerprint from the server, not from the local system) and what the recommended method for client authentication is (client key, not password).